# VBA variant array redim/resize inside function

Tags: vba

I want to pass a Nx1 array into a function, and get back a Mx1 array (i.e. just truncate the array down to size M). I have a strong preference for doing this as efficiently as possible.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
Public Function cutarray(A As Variant, M As Integer)
    ReDim Preserve A(1 To M)
    cutarray = A
End Function
```

This seems like it should be obvious, I'm just missing something.

Also I should mention I'm calling this function directly from excel, e.g. `=cutarray(A1:A5000,75)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. When you pass in an array from excel, it's actually a two dimensional array with an X dimension of 1. ReDim only changes the right most dimension (which in this case is 1), so any M bigger than one is subscript-out-of-range.

This fixes it, but is sort of inefficient:

```
Public Function cutarray(A As Variant, i As Integer)
    A = Application.Transpose(A)
    ReDim Preserve A(0 To i)
    A = Application.Transpose(A)
    cutarray = A
End Function
```

Comment: you dont need the second transpose,  Use TypeName(A)  this will tell you that when A enters the Function it is a Range and not a Variant()  when you use Transpose it turns it into a Variant()

Answer (score 1):

First you need to read your question and tells us what is not working.  I am going to guess that you are working on a fixed length array

```
dim v(4) <-- is a fixed size array.
```

this will cause an error when attempting to redim. to resolve you would declare an empty array and then redim it to the size

```
Dim v()
redim v(4)
```

now you would be able to pass this to your function and have it return without error.   Also as a note, arrays start at index 0 unless you set base option 1.  Keep that in mind when you are resizing the array or you lose the first element.

Comment: It doesn't actually show the error, but if I wrap it in an "on error go to", the the "Err.Description" is `Subcript out of Range`.

I'm passing in the array directly from Excel, e.g. `=cutarray(A1:A5000,75)`, making it a Variant(1 to 5000, 1 to 1) object when it gets into the VBA. I don't know if that's considered fixed length, but I think that precludes me from declaring it first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you also need to set the argument as dynamic array. If not required, at least good practice to document call.

Public Function Cutarray(a() as variant, m as interger)

Also make sure you are not attempting to change the lower bound, that would generate an error if your input array was initially declared with 0 base. You can change the upper bound with preserve but not lower.

I would just change this to:
Redim Preserve A(M)

Comment: I just tried changing it to `A() as Variant`, and changing it to `A(0 To i) `. Neither seemed to work.